# Leaflet map doesn’t work after adding a new control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, controls, geodjango

After adding [Leaflet.MousePosition](https://github.com/ardhi/Leaflet.MousePosition) my map doesn’t show.

```
var lmap = new L.map("lmap", {
  zoomControl: false,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 3,
}).setView([34.543896, 63.160652], 6);
L.control.zoom({
  position: 'topright'
}).addTo(lmap);
lmap.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen({position: 'bottomleft'}));
L.control.mousePosition({position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(lmap);
```

[image: t]

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: L.control.mousePosition is not a function

Comment: have you added the library to your project?

Comment: it hasn't mentioned how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `map` but you have to use `lmap`

```
L.control.mousePosition({position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(lmap);
```

Also you have to add the library src to your project.

Add following to your html file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-mouse-position@1.2.0/src/L.Control.MousePosition.min.js"></script>
```